# Implementing F-measure metric when predicted values are multi-class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics

I want to implement the F-measure metric in python in order to handle multi-class for predicted values.

In fact, predicted values y_pred are multi-class and corrected values are one class.

Example:

y_pred = [[11,12], 12, 12, [11,12],...]

y_true = [11, 12, 11, 12,...]

How can i compute the F-measure in that case ? and how to implement it ?

I tested the following code (founded in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification)  with two files file1.csv (including all predicting classes, each row can contain more than one class) and file2.csv (including all corrected values, each row contains one only class):

```
import pandas as pd

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    i = set(y_true).intersection(y_pred)    
    len1 = len(y_pred)    
    if len1 == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return len(i) / len1


def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    i = set(y_true).intersection(y_pred)
    return len(i) / len(y_true)


def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    p = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    r = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    if p + r == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 2 * (p * r) / (p + r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    y_pred_df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', skipinitialspace=True, sep='\t', header=None)
    y_pred = y_pred_df.values

    y_true_df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None)
    y_true = y_true_df.values


    print(f1(y_true[:,0], y_pred[:,0]))
```

The above code does not work.

How can i implement F-measure in my case ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Made an answer out of my comment

Comment: could you please say, what specifically does not work? Is there an error message? Is the result wrong? What does you data set look like?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the already implemented [f1-score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)? If you want to have a metric that works well with scikit-learn you might want to use  the [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer)-function. Additionally, check the [model-evaluation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#model-evaluation) section in the docs.